# Can't pipe stdout of a python script that runs in background to file

Tags: pipe, raspbian, background-process, rc.local

I have a python script `myscript.py` on a RaspberryPi with Raspbian that starts on boot via `rc.local` file. Since it has infinite loop in it I need to run it in background. So far so good but I also want to log this script's stdout to file with a pipe but can't get it working. My `rc.local` file looks like this:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/myscript.py >> /var/www/html/log.log &
```

My `log.log` file has 666 permission so my script should be able to write to it right? Yet it does not.

Comment: I think you want to send output to a file within the python script.  `import sys
sys.stdout = open('file', 'w')`.  With the recent bash versions you can do something like  `...&>> /var/www/html/log.log &`

Comment: @ValentinBajrami `import sys sys.stdout = open('file', 'w')` didn't do the trick. It works when run from console but still does not write to the file when run at boot within `rc.local`

Comment: But that is an `rc.local` thing then. On what system are you running this?

Answer (score 6):

Output of python is buffered by default, you have to use "-u" parameter to avoid buffering. So this should do the trick:

```
/usr/bin/python3 -u /home/pi/myscript.py >> /var/www/html/log.log &
```

Comment: Kudos for noting this! Many programs do the same thing--standard out is buffered by default (standard error is usually unbuffered) so the kernel does not actually display the buffered output until the buffer is full. This includes output redirection: It's not sent to the redirected file until the buffer is full. Additionally, some programs may do their own buffering before even sending output to the kernel to be displayed-or-buffered by the kernel.